# Ionic 2 : plugin FilePath error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I tried to follow this tutorial : https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-images/

But when I import "FilePath" I have this error :

```
[12:06:45]  typescript: C:/xampp/htdocs/AppFineMobile/src/pages/send-document/send-document.ts, line: 58
            Cannot find name 'FilePath'.

      L57:  if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
      L58:    FilePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
      L59:        .then(filePath => {

[12:06:45]  build finished in 4.21 s
```

I run all this commands and the plugin is successful installed :

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-filepath
```

[image]

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: did you check if ``FilePath`` exist in your node_modules folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>At the top of your `send-document.ts` you should add the `FilePath` import:</strike>

```
import {FilePath} from 'ionic-native';
```

TypeScript says that it cannot find it, which suggests you forgot to import it.

According to the [github readme](https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath) of this plugin, it creates a `window.FilePath` variable when you install the plugin. There are also no typings available.

My guess is that you actually have to remove the `FilePath` import and just declare the variable itself at the top:

```
declare const FilePath: any;
```

Comment: Sur I did it, but I have an error here. And my IDE underline the import.